# android: i want to use DRM in Market

Tags: android, drm

I want to use Digital rights management (DRM) in my application.

Isn't there source that uses DrmStore?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html

Comment: May help...  [DRM Example Source](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/provider/DrmStore.java.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

DRM in this context is somewhat vague, and can mean a couple of things:

### Application Licensing

If you're trying to copy-protect your application, you can use the new Android Market [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) feature.

Some more blog posts on the topic can be found here:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/licensing-service-for-android.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/licensing-service-technology-highlights.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/08/licensing-server-news.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html

### Media Content Protection

If you're trying to protect media content and can't use an in-app content protection method, you may be interested in the new system DRM framework in Android 3.0 (the `android.drm` package). Details for using this framework are a bit scarce currently because there are no widely available native DRM plugins/agents to interface with (as of this writing, May 2011). Additionally, your implementation may vary depending on the plugin you'd be using.

More information on this new framework can be currently found in the [Android 3.0 Platform](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html) description document:

> > **Digital rights management (DRM)**
> >
> > New extensible digital rights management (DRM) framework for checking and enforcing digital rights. It's implemented in two architectural layers:
> >
> > - A DRM framework API, which is exposed to applications and runs through the Dalvik VM for standard applications.
> > - A native code DRM manager that implements the framework API and exposes an interface for DRM plug-ins to handle rights management and decryption for various DRM schemes.
> >
> > For application developers, the framework offers an abstract, unified API that simplifies the management of protected content. The API hides the complexity of DRM operations and allows a consistent operation mode for both protected and unprotected content, and across a variety of DRM schemes.
> >
> > For device manufacturers, content owners, and Internet digital media providers the DRM framework?s plugin API provides a means of adding support for a DRM scheme of choice into the Android system, for secure enforcement of content protection.
> >
> > The preview release does not provide any native DRM plug-ins for checking and enforcing digital rights. However, device manufacturers may ship DRM plug-ins with their devices.
> >
> > You can find all of the DRM APIs in the `android.drm` package.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great advice. Have you got any information in regards to the microsoft playready support on android or the silverlight-based drm?

Comment: @Markiz — currently, if you need to use PlayReady in-app DRM you'll need to work with a third-party DRM provider that supports Android.